# ANDROID: Converting inputted numbers to words

Tags: java, android

Our assignment states that we write a program that will input a number up to 6 digits and will convert the numbers into words.. ex: 123 = one hundred twenty three. I AM CLUELESS! Then I found this site http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html 
but I don't really understand how to convert it into android.

please help me..please.

here is my Main_Activity.xml:

```
package com.example.torres;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    final EditText numbers =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText results = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Button btnConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);     
    btnConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
         String numberz =numbers.getText().toString();
         try {
             final long number = Long.parseLong(numberz);
             String returnz = Words.convert(number); 
         } catch ( NumberFormatException e) {
             //Toast.makeToast("illegal number or empty number" , toast.long)
         }

                       }  });


        }}
```

and here is my Words.java

```
package com.example.torres;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Words  {




      private static final String[] tensNames = {
        "",
        " ten",
        " twenty",
        " thirty",
        " forty",
        " fifty",
        " sixty",
        " seventy",
        " eighty",
        " ninety"
      };

      private static final String[] numNames = {
        "",
        " one",
        " two",
        " three",
        " four",
        " five",
        " six",
        " seven",
        " eight",
        " nine",
        " ten",
        " eleven",
        " twelve",
        " thirteen",
        " fourteen",
        " fifteen",
        " sixteen",
        " seventeen",
        " eighteen",
        " nineteen"
      };

      private Words() {}


    public static String convertLessThanOneThousand(int number) {
        String soFar;

        if (number % 100 < 20){
          soFar = numNames[number % 100];
          number /= 100;
        }
        else {
          soFar = numNames[number % 10];
          number /= 10;

          soFar = tensNames[number % 10] + soFar;
          number /= 10;
        }
        if (number == 0) return soFar;
        return numNames[number] + " hundred" + soFar;
      }


      public static String convert(long number) {
        // 0 to 999 999 999 999
        if (number == 0) { return "zero"; }

        String snumber = Long.toString(number);

        // pad with "0"
        String mask = "000000000000";
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(mask);
        snumber = df.format(number);

        // XXXnnnnnnnnn
        int billions = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(0,3));
        // nnnXXXnnnnnn
        int millions  = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(3,6));
        // nnnnnnXXXnnn
        int hundredThousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(6,9));
        // nnnnnnnnnXXX
        int thousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(9,12));

        String tradBillions;
        switch (billions) {
        case 0:
          tradBillions = "";
          break;
        case 1 :
          tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions)
          + " billion ";
          break;
        default :
          tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions)
          + " billion ";
        }
        String result =  tradBillions;

        String tradMillions;
        switch (millions) {
        case 0:
          tradMillions = "";
          break;
        case 1 :
          tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions)
             + " million ";
          break;
        default :
          tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions)
             + " million ";
        }
        result =  result + tradMillions;

        String tradHundredThousands;
        switch (hundredThousands) {
        case 0:
          tradHundredThousands = "";
          break;
        case 1 :
          tradHundredThousands = "one thousand ";
          break;
        default :
          tradHundredThousands = convertLessThanOneThousand(hundredThousands)
             + " thousand ";
        }
        result =  result + tradHundredThousands;

        String tradThousand;
        tradThousand = convertLessThanOneThousand(thousands);
        result =  result + tradThousand;

        // remove extra spaces!
        return result.replaceAll("^\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\b\\s{2,}\\b", " ");}




      }
```

The only problem now is that nothing happens lol

Comment: Why You have mixed up the java compling code with Android ?

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't understand it >.<

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make separate class for **EnglishNumberToWords**  as in the example link.

and in your button click you have to just call

```
String return_val_in_english =   EnglishNumberToWords.convert(YOUR_NUMBER_TO_CONVERT);
```

[image]

```
public class EnglishNumberToWords {

private static final String[] tensNames = { "", " ten", " twenty", " thirty", " forty",
        " fifty", " sixty", " seventy", " eighty", " ninety" };

private static final String[] numNames = { "", " one", " two", " three", " four", " five",
        " six", " seven", " eight", " nine", " ten", " eleven", " twelve", " thirteen",
        " fourteen", " fifteen", " sixteen", " seventeen", " eighteen", " nineteen" };

private static String convertLessThanOneThousand(int number)
{
    String soFar;

    if (number % 100 < 20)
    {
        soFar = numNames[number % 100];
        number /= 100;
    } else
    {
        soFar = numNames[number % 10];
        number /= 10;

        soFar = tensNames[number % 10] + soFar;
        number /= 10;
    }
    if (number == 0)
        return soFar;
    return numNames[number] + " hundred" + soFar;
}

public static String convert(long number)
{
    // 0 to 999 999 999 999
    if (number == 0)
    {
        return "zero";
    }

    String snumber = Long.toString(number);

    // pad with "0"
    String mask = "000000000000";
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(mask);
    snumber = df.format(number);

    // XXXnnnnnnnnn
    int billions = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(0, 3));
    // nnnXXXnnnnnn
    int millions = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(3, 6));
    // nnnnnnXXXnnn
    int hundredThousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(6, 9));
    // nnnnnnnnnXXX
    int thousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(9, 12));

    String tradBillions;
    switch (billions)
    {
        case 0:
            tradBillions = "";
            break;
        case 1:
            tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions) + " billion ";
            break;
        default:
            tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions) + " billion ";
    }
    String result = tradBillions;

    String tradMillions;
    switch (millions)
    {
        case 0:
            tradMillions = "";
            break;
        case 1:
            tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions) + " million ";
            break;
        default:
            tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions) + " million ";
    }
    result = result + tradMillions;

    String tradHundredThousands;
    switch (hundredThousands)
    {
        case 0:
            tradHundredThousands = "";
            break;
        case 1:
            tradHundredThousands = "one thousand ";
            break;
        default:
            tradHundredThousands = convertLessThanOneThousand(hundredThousands) + " thousand ";
    }
    result = result + tradHundredThousands;

    String tradThousand;
    tradThousand = convertLessThanOneThousand(thousands);
    result = result + tradThousand;

    // remove extra spaces!
    return result.replaceAll("^\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\b\\s{2,}\\b", " ");
}

}
```

Comment: oh! how do I make a separate class sir?

Comment: It means you can create new class file in your project. Are you new to java or what. It's very basic concept.

Comment: what do you mean with (Your_number_to_convert)?

Comment: it's an integer value which you want to convert into English words. :D

Comment: if its from a textview sir, how to i put it there?

Comment: covert it from String to long value coming from textview via getText().toString() method.

Comment: how about the meaning of return_vcal_in_english

Comment: Have you checked value of returnz variable , lolz.. and don't call me sir ! :P :D

Comment: the value of returnz is the one i want to send to words sir >.< Oh i mean friend haha

Comment: no still not working sir, i dont understand why it does not work yet

Comment: where is the edit sir? WOW i saw your picture of the app...WOW

Comment: from my editted post, did you change anything sir? mines does not work. I tried to input numbers thenwhen I click button nothing happens

Comment: sir can you post ur code here, mine really doesnt work

Comment: just Log value of your returnz variable and let me know what value it's having.

Comment: how do i Log the value sir

Comment: set it in another textview as i have done. simple. or use Log.i() method.

Comment: and where do I put it sir?

Comment: You are the best sir thank you very much! I will study this for I find it really hard haha thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

Posting my answer here because can be helpful to someone else...

```kotlin
import android.icu.text.MessageFormat
import java.util.Locale

fun Double.toWords(language: String, country: String): String {
    val formatter = MessageFormat(
        "{0,spellout,currency}", 
        Locale(language, country)
    )
    return formatter.format(arrayOf(this))
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.ui.text.intl.Locale

// ...

(12345678.99).toWords(Locale.current.language, Locale.current.region)

// OR,

(12345678.99).toWords("en", "US") // For static local
```

This call will return the string

> twelve million three hundred forty-five thousand six hundred seventy-eight point nine nine

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/MessageFormat

Comment: Hi, this solution worked great!
Is there any way though to make first letter capital?

Answer (score 6):

Above all the solution is working fine, Only problem is that this is **not working for all language** because all country is not having the same set of rules to convert a number into word so we need to write a separate algorithm for each country,

**Solution**

[ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/home/why-use-icu4j) is an international Unicode component library that is allowed so many utilities regarding language translation follow below steps.

- **Step 1** Add ICU4J in your app level gradle like below

  ```
  dependencies {
      implementation group: 'com.ibm.icu', name: 'icu4j', version: '51.1' 
  }
  ```
- **Step 2** Define this method

  ```
  private String convertIntoWords(Double str,String language,String Country) {
        Locale local = new Locale(language, Country);
        RuleBasedNumberFormat ruleBasedNumberFormat = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(local, RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT);
        return ruleBasedNumberFormat.format(str);
  }
  ```
- **Step 3** Now you can call this method like below

  ```
  double value=165;
  String english=convertIntoWords(value,"en","US"); //one hundred and sixty-five
  /*Peruvion*/
  String Spanish=convertIntoWords(value,"es","PE"); //ciento sesenta y cinco
  ```

You can change language and country based on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

**Java Class for that :-**

```
public class NumberToWordsConverter {

        public static final String[] units = {"", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four",
                "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve",
                "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen",
                "Eighteen", "Nineteen"};

        public static final String[] tens = {
                "",        // 0
                "",        // 1
                "Twenty",    // 2
                "Thirty",    // 3
                "Forty",    // 4
                "Fifty",    // 5
                "Sixty",    // 6
                "Seventy",    // 7
                "Eighty",    // 8
                "Ninety"    // 9
        };

        public static String convert(final int n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                return "Minus " + convert(-n);
            }

            if (n < 20) {
                return units[n];
            }

            if (n < 100) {
                return tens[n / 10] + ((n % 10 != 0) ? " " : "") + units[n % 10];
            }

            if (n < 1000) {
                return units[n / 100] + " Hundred" + ((n % 100 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 100);
            }

            if (n < 100000) {
                return convert(n / 1000) + " Thousand" + ((n % 10000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 1000);
            }

            if (n < 10000000) {
                return convert(n / 100000) + " Lakh" + ((n % 100000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 100000);
            }

            return convert(n / 10000000) + " Crore" + ((n % 10000000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 10000000);
        }
    }
```

**Implementation in your main class.**
You can have separate method like the follwing or you can directly use without separate method.

```
private String numToWords (int n){ //optional
        NumberToWordsConverter ntw = new NumberToWordsConverter(); // directly implement this
        return ntw.convert(n);
    } //optional
```

Answer (score -3):

You have done all the work just display String returnz in a text field like this

```
 results.setText(returnz);
```